# how to find image surface normals for water surface?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, signal-processing, computer-science

I want to find surface normals for an image. I have 2 water surface images. First one is still water, and second one is a moving image.

I found each corrospondent pixels for both of images by using normalized correlation. therefore, I have displacement for all pixels in x and y direction.

what i am asking is how i can find the water surface normals for each point?
I think displacement in x and y direction can help me for finding surface normals, but I don't know how to move forward.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: adding some sample images might help.

Comment: I i dont have permission to add images. B